# How to close login.html file after user login, using flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, redirect

When a button is clicked on `main.html` page. It then redirects to `login.html`, In `login.html` when submit is pressed it has `action="{ (login) }"`. In flask i have route for login. So, Now can i close that `login.html` page using flask(in `route("/login")`)

Comment: Maybe you need to _redirect_ user to another page after login not just close the current window or tab?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `action="{(login)}"` try using

```
action="{{url_for('login')}}"
```

The url_for function is used to refer to URLs based on their functions.

Comment: My doubt is how to close that page(login.html) after user clicks on submit ,through flask

Comment: @deepakchinnu if you have sent the form data to the url ```/login```, then you would have to return some data so you should give a "Login Successful" or "Failed" message by returning either some text or rendering a template or you can even redirect the user to the destination he/she wants to go.